# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in chrome running in disabled web security mode

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, cors

Am getting the error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access" even in chrome's disable web security mode. It was not happening till day before yesterday. I think its because of chrome's update. Is there any possible solution for it ?

Comment: I assume you are calling a server side api, it is most likely something is changed on the server, did you check your backend?

Comment: Yup we had checked our backend. There is no change in backend from past couple of days. Adding additional parameter, "--user-data-dir" for launching the chrome in separate user profile mode, made it work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added (--user-data-dir="C:/chromeTemp") in addition to --disable-web-security parameter to make it work.

So, if we are using the chrome short cut to launch chrome, the target input field of it, in the properties of it will now look like follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/chromeTemp" --disable-web-security
```

It seemes that new chrome's update with security patches have made this change to be done.(It was not required earlier)